Prove the existence of 2 specific lenghted words given a DFA
Let $A$ a DFA with $n$ states.
Prove:
If $|L(A)|=\infty \implies \exists w,w'$ s.t $0\leq |w|-|w'|\leq n$ and $|w|\leq 2n$.

The part I'm not so sure about is the one where I pick $w_1,w_2$. I'm not sure if my assumptions are correct and explained properly.
My Proof:
$|L(A)|=\infty \implies \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ exists $w \in L(A)$ s.t $|w|\geq m$. If this weren't the case then assume exists some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall w \in L(A): |w|\leq M$. This would imply that $|L(A)| \leq |\Sigma|^M$.
Let $w \in L(A)$ a word of infinite length. Deduce in the run of $A$ on $w$ exists some cycle $C$ s.t $|C| \leq n$ since $n$ is the number of states in $A$.
Deduce $w_1 :=$ a double cycle $C$ satisfies $w_1 \in L(A)$.
In addition deduce $w_2 :=$ a single cycle $C$ satisfies $w_2 \in L(A)$.
Denote, $w_1,w_2$ satisfy the question requirements.

Questions asking us to check whether your solution is correct only are considered off-topic (per http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/). Please pinpoint your doubt and provide a specific question to which a meaty answer can resolve your doubt whether your answer is correct or not.
